# need xpath where the next descendant that has text is returned

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, axes

I am trying to write a locator where the next text descendant is returned. I wont know the text. The following xpath works:

```
//*[@id='myChart']//label[contains(text(),"Show:")]/following::div[4]
```

but I dont like the div[4] as this could easily change. The element is the first div type descendant under show that contains text. Any suggestions?

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following clauses:

- *the next text descendant*
- *I wont know the text*
- *div[4] as this could easily change*
- *element is the first div type descendant*

To locate the element a couple of effective approaches are as follows:

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  //*[@id='myChart']//label[contains(., "Show")]//div[text()]
  ```
- Using *xpath* with *`descendant`*:

  ```
  //*[@id='myChart']//label[contains(., "Show")]//descendant::div[text()]
  ```
- Using *xpath* with *`following`*:

  ```
  //*[@id='myChart']//label[contains(., "Show")]//following::div[text()]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you:

```
//*[@id='myChart']//label[contains(text(),"Show:")]//div[text()]
```

To give more confident answer we need to see the actual page / XML.
In case the desired `div` is a direct child of the `label` containing the "Show:" the above expression can be presided to

```
//*[@id='myChart']//label[contains(text(),"Show:")]/div[text()]
```